# How can i send this login request each minute?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I want to send a request each minute to my users/login API , if I put `setinterval (login , 6*6000)` in the endpoint in doesn't work with async await , if I put it in the `index.html` the login function isn't declared in other pages and console: `login is not declared in profile`.

The login end point located in the React directoy:

```js
export const login = async user => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('users/login', {
            username: user.username,
            password: user.password
        });
        localStorage.setItem('usertoken', response.data);
        return response.data;
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

And this is login handling in React:

```js
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
    };

    login(user).then(res => {
        if (res) {  
            this.props.history.push(`/profile`);
        } else {
            console.log('couldnt login');
        }
    })
}
```

> Edit : 
>   I have done this, it is making a request but not logging in:

```js
export const login = async user => {
    try {
        setInterval(async () => {
            const response = await axios.post('users/login', {
                username: user.username,
                password: user.password
            });
            localStorage.setItem('usertoken', response.data);
            return response.data;
        } , 6*1000);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to send a login request every minute? Also, you current code is sending a request every 6 seconds, not a minute.

Answer (score 0):

As its name suggests, you login function should simply do that:

```js
/**
 * Performs login and returns the promise
 * Sets the user to local storage on success
 * Logs and throws on failure
 */
export const login = (user) => (
    axios.post('users/login', {
        username: user.username,
        password: user.password
    }).then((response) => {
        localStorage.setItem('usertoken', response.data);
        return response.data;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Login Failed');
        throw error;
    })
);
```

Then, your `onSubmit` function should handle this login loop on its own. I've also added a `loginInterval` attribute as well as a `stopLoggingIn` method in the component in case you want to evetually stop logging in indefinitely.

```js
import { login } from 'somewhere';

// Component code...

/**
 * Performs login every minute
 */
onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
    };

    this.loginInterval = setInterval(() => {
        login(user).then((data) => {
            if (data) {  
                this.props.history.push('/profile');
            }
            else {
                console.log('Something went wrong');
            }
        });
    }, 60 * 1000);
}

/**
 * Clears the login interval
 * In case you want to stop logging in in a loop
 */
stopLoggingIn = () => {
    clearInterval(this.loginInterval);
}

// Rest of component code...
```

As a final note, you may have noticed that I did not use `async` or `await`, and that's because you do not really need them in your case. Redirection to the application is only performed on successful login and there's no reason to block the code with `await` as I don't see any critical statemenets that should only be executed after login and that are not in the callback of the login request.